# How to print the data from the FILE

Tags: c, file, eof

I have my c language exams soon, and I need some help with FILE. So...
The task is: user input data from console to file ("prod.txt"), then I need to print the data from file to my display. I use `!=EOF` to print it, and it's not working. I've tried to use ==5 (number of variable), and it`s not woorking too. My code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Windows.h>

struct icx //структурный файл для данных входного файла
{
    char media[100]; float year1937; float year1940; float year1950; float year1958;
};

struct icx a; 
struct icx b;
struct icx c;
struct icx d;
struct icx e;


char ss1[110] = "________________________________________________________________________________________";
char ss2[110] = "________________________________________________________________________________________";

void print_menu()
{
    system("cls"); // очищаем экран
    printf("\nМеню\n");
    printf("\n1. Создание исходного файла.");
    printf("\n2. Вывод на экран содержимого исходного файла.");
    printf("\n3. Обработка исходного файла.");
    printf("\n4. Вывод на экран содержимого выходного файла.");
    printf("\n5. Конец работы.\n");
    printf("\n");
}

int get_variant(int count)
{
    int variant;

    // пока ввод некорректен, сообщаем об этом и просим повторить его
    while (scanf_s("%i", &variant) != 1 || variant < 1 || variant > count)
    {
        printf("Некорректный ввод. Попробуйте снова: "); // выводим сообщение об ошибке
        scanf_s("%i", &variant); // считываем строку повторно
    }
    printf("\n");
    return variant;
}

void shapka1() {
    printf("%s\n", ss1);
    printf("! Средства массовой информации ! 1937 ! 1940 ! 1950 ! 1958!\n");
    printf("%s\n", ss1);
}

void shapka2()
{
    printf("%s\n", ss2);
    printf("! Вид СМИ ! Доля в 1937 ! Доля в 1940 ! Доля в 1950 ! Доля в 1958 ! \n");
    printf("%s\n", ss2);
}

void read_print_icx(FILE *prod) {
    struct icx str;
    printf("Входной файл\n");
    shapka1();
    while (fscanf_s(prod, "%s%f%f%f%f", str.media, _countof(str.media), &str.year1937, &str.year1940, &str.year1950, &str.year1958) != EOF) {
        printf("\n! %-17s ! %5.1f ! %5.1f ! %5.1f ! %5.1f !", str.media, str.year1937, str.year1940, str.year1950, str.year1958);
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s\n", ss1);
    }
    
}

void read_for_job(FILE *prod) {

    fscanf_s(prod, "%s%f%f%f%f", a.media, _countof(a.media), &a.year1937, &a.year1940, &a.year1950, &a.year1958);
    fscanf_s(prod, "%s%f%f%f%f", b.media, _countof(b.media), &b.year1937, &b.year1940, &b.year1950, &b.year1958);
    fscanf_s(prod, "%s%f%f%f%f", c.media, _countof(c.media), &c.year1937, &c.year1940, &c.year1950, &c.year1958);
    fscanf_s(prod, "%s%f%f%f%f", d.media, _countof(d.media), &d.year1937, &d.year1940, &d.year1950, &d.year1958);
    fscanf_s(prod, "%s%f%f%f%f", e.media, _countof(e.media), &e.year1937, &e.year1940, &e.year1950, &e.year1958);
}

void write_prod(FILE *prod) { // п1 меню
    
    if (&prod == NULL) {
        perror("Failed: ");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Ввод данных таблицы : \n");
    scanf_s("%s%f%f%f%f", a.media, (unsigned)_countof(a.media), &a.year1937, &a.year1940, &a.year1950, &a.year1958);
    scanf_s("%s%f%f%f%f", b.media, (unsigned)_countof(b.media), &b.year1937, &b.year1940, &b.year1950, &b.year1958);
    scanf_s("%s%f%f%f%f", c.media, (unsigned)_countof(c.media), &c.year1937, &c.year1940, &c.year1950, &c.year1958);
    scanf_s("%s%f%f%f%f", d.media, (unsigned)_countof(d.media), &d.year1937, &d.year1940, &d.year1950, &d.year1958);
    scanf_s("%s%f%f%f%f", e.media, (unsigned)_countof(e.media), &e.year1937, &e.year1940, &e.year1950, &e.year1958);
    fprintf(prod, "\n %-14s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f ", a.media, a.year1937, a.year1940, a.year1950, a.year1958);
    fprintf(prod, "\n %-14s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f ", b.media, b.year1937, b.year1940, b.year1950, b.year1958);
    fprintf(prod, "\n %-14s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f ", c.media, c.year1937, c.year1940, c.year1950, c.year1958);
    fprintf(prod, "\n %-14s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f ", d.media, d.year1937, d.year1940, d.year1950, d.year1958);
    fprintf(prod, "\n %-14s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f ", e.media, e.year1937, e.year1940, e.year1950, e.year1958);
    fclose(prod);
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    SetConsoleCP(1251); // Ввод с консоли в кодировке 1251
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    FILE *prod;
    fopen_s(&prod, "prod.txt", "w");
    
    //int variant; //пункт меню
    float oldradio1937, oldradio1940, oldradio1950, oldradio1958; // процент распространения трансляционных приемников
    float radio1937, radio1940, radio1950, radio1958; // процент распространения радио
    
    //fopen_s(&prod, "prod.txt", "w");
    write_prod(prod);
    read_print_icx(prod);
    printf("Выполнение расчетов\n");
    oldradio1937 = b.year1937 / a.year1937;
    oldradio1940 = b.year1940 / a.year1940;
    oldradio1950 = b.year1950 / a.year1950;
    oldradio1958 = b.year1958 / a.year1958;

    radio1937 = d.year1937 / c.year1937;
    radio1940 = d.year1940 / c.year1940;
    radio1950 = d.year1950 / c.year1950;
    radio1958 = d.year1958 / c.year1958;

    printf("\n%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f", oldradio1937, oldradio1940, oldradio1950, oldradio1958, radio1937, radio1940, radio1950, radio1958);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that problem is in this part:

```
while (fscanf_s(prod, "%s%f%f%f%f", str.media, _countof(str.media), &str.year1937, &str.year1940, &str.year1950, &str.year1958) != EOF) {
    printf("\n! %-17s ! %5.1f ! %5.1f ! %5.1f ! %5.1f !", str.media, str.year1937, str.year1940, str.year1950, str.year1958);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n", ss1);
}
```

I have no idea what to do to fix it, even try `gets` and `puts`. No result.
Please help me.

Comment: Your write function closes the file. What opens it after that happens?

Comment: Not related but in `get_variant` you ask for input twice in your loop and ignore one of the values. You probably don't want to use `scanf` inside the loop.

Comment: Scott Johnson, do you mean, that I need first open the file again and then print data?

Comment: Gerhardh, thanx for advice.

Comment: @Кирилл Боровой yes. You can neither read nor write a file that isn't open. Also be sure to open it for reading when you want to read from it.

Comment: @L. Scott Johnson, thanx. I try to use it.

Comment: Yes, you have to reopen it. You are closing the file in your `write_prod(prod);` function and then trying to read from `prod` afterwards in `read_print_icx(prod)`, Also when opening the file again, use fopen_s(&prod, "prod.txt", **"r"**); - cos opening again in write mode its content gets erased.

Comment: @L. Scott Johnson I've tried, and it's working. Thank you guys. Have a nice weekend.